Remove Empty Line at Top Command Prompt Start Up Display
This question is a continuation of post Modify Windows CommandLine Start Up Text
After I succeeded in modifying the cmd startup display from its origin, so that it looked like this:

CMD:

Still there is a blank line at the top.
So, How do I remove it?, becomes only:
CMD:

Like my modified PowerShell Startup below:
PS7:

with no blank line at top.
Of course, command CLS only clearing the text displayed, not line.

Update:
I tried pressing keyboard keys, and got CTRL + L on my PC. Maybe it's different on other PCs.
But this is only temporary. Still looking for a permanent setting

I don't think what you want is possible.

@Gantendo of course, there is no problem, because it's only modify the display

Cmd does not have an option for that – according to the source code that's available on GitHub, printing the empty line before each prompt is literally part of the same code that displays the actual prompt (in clex.c) and there is no hidden option to skip it.
Current versions of Windows support VT220-style terminal control sequences (the ones that let you add formatting to the prompt), so you could add the "Move cursor up" sequence at the very beginning of the PROMPT variable – so that every time Cmd prints out the empty line (and moves the cursor down), it will then immediately move the cursor back up by one.
The control sequence ESC [ 1 A or "Cursor Up 1 Times" would be written as $E[1A in the Cmd.exe PROMPT syntax; for example:
set PROMPT=$E[1ACMD:

This only works on fairly recent Windows versions that support the ANSI/VT220 control sequences in the console; for example, it will not work on Windows 7.
It also has the small downside(?) that if you press Enter at an empty command line, it will look like nothing is happening because Cmd doesn't print the empty line in that situation, so the cursor moves right back to where it was before your Enter keypress.

It's also possible that third-party mods such as clink/Cmder could achieve this, as clink already implements a lot of changes to the text-input parts of Cmd. I've not tried any of those mods.

According to ur answer, By Modify Autorun in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor with value (fltmc >nul&& SET PROMPT=$E[1ACMD# || SET PROMPT=$E[1ACMD: )& CLS Work Properly on my PC. Thanks.

I would recommend pointing Autorun to a full .cmd script; having it all in a file is going to be easier to edit.

Thanks for the advice. because there is only a little code.
